# Why I failed to map over snapshot.data from Cloud Firestore of FlutterFire?

Tags: firebase, flutter

I am not getting any error message, but the program is not running anything inside the map function. I can print the value of historySnapshot.data which shows a list of WorkoutHistory, but I do not know why I cannot map over it.  I have checked by historySnapshot.hasData() and historySnapshot.data != null and they did not show that the data is null.

This is the code:

```
class _HomeScreenState extends State<HomeScreen> {
  DateTime startTime = DateTime.utc(2021, 1, 1);
  DateTime endTime = DateTime.utc(2050, 1, 1);
  late Stream<List<WorkoutHistory>> _workoutHistoryListStream;
  late Stream<List<Workout>> _workoutListStream;

  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    _workoutHistoryListStream = context
        .read<FirestoreUtils>()
        .getWorkoutHistoryListStreamByTime(startTime, endTime);
    _workoutListStream = context.read<FirestoreUtils>().getWorkoutListStream();
  }
```

Here is the StreamBuilder:

```
Expanded(
            child: StreamBuilder<List<WorkoutHistory>>(
              stream: _workoutHistoryListStream,
              builder: (BuildContext context,
                  AsyncSnapshot<List<WorkoutHistory>> historySnapshot) {
                return StreamBuilder<List<Workout>>(
                    stream: _workoutListStream,
                    builder: (BuildContext context,
                        AsyncSnapshot<List<Workout>> workoutSnapshot) {
                      if (historySnapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text('Error: ${historySnapshot.error}');
                      } else if (workoutSnapshot.hasError) {
                        return Text('Error: ${workoutSnapshot.error}');
                      } else if (historySnapshot.connectionState ==
                              ConnectionState.waiting ||
                          workoutSnapshot.connectionState ==
                              ConnectionState.waiting) {
                        return Text('Loading...');
                      } else {
                        print('Carousel logic start');

                        if (historySnapshot.data == null ||
                            workoutSnapshot.data == null ||
                            !historySnapshot.hasData) {
                          print('snapshot is null');
                        }

                        List<ZoneInfo> zoneList = [
                          ZoneInfo(
                            zone: 0,
                            status: ZoneStatus.isDisabled,
                            attempt: 0,
                            make: 0,
                          ),
                          ZoneInfo(
                            zone: 1,
                            status: ZoneStatus.isDisabled,
                            attempt: 0,
                            make: 0,
                          ),
                          ZoneInfo(
                            zone: 2,
                            status: ZoneStatus.isDisabled,
                            attempt: 0,
                            make: 0,
                          ),
                          ZoneInfo(
                            zone: 3,
                            status: ZoneStatus.isDisabled,
                            attempt: 0,
                            make: 0,
                          ),
                          ZoneInfo(
                            zone: 4,
                            status: ZoneStatus.isDisabled,
                            attempt: 0,
                            make: 0,
                          ),
                          ZoneInfo(
                            zone: 5,
                            status: ZoneStatus.isDisabled,
                            attempt: 0,
                            make: 0,
                          ),
                          ZoneInfo(
                            zone: 6,
                            status: ZoneStatus.isDisabled,
                            attempt: 0,
                            make: 0,
                          ),
                          ZoneInfo(
                            zone: 7,
                            status: ZoneStatus.isDisabled,
                            attempt: 0,
                            make: 0,
                          ),
                          ZoneInfo(
                            zone: 8,
                            status: ZoneStatus.isDisabled,
                            attempt: 0,
                            make: 0,
                          ),
                          ZoneInfo(
                            zone: 9,
                            status: ZoneStatus.isDisabled,
                            attempt: 0,
                            make: 0,
                          ),
                          ZoneInfo(
                            zone: 10,
                            status: ZoneStatus.isDisabled,
                            attempt: 0,
                            make: 0,
                          ),
                          ZoneInfo(
                            zone: 11,
                            status: ZoneStatus.isDisabled,
                            attempt: 0,
                            make: 0,
                          ),
                          ZoneInfo(
                            zone: 12,
                            status: ZoneStatus.isDisabled,
                            attempt: 0,
                            make: 0,
                          ),
                          ZoneInfo(
                            zone: 13,
                            status: ZoneStatus.isDisabled,
                            attempt: 0,
                            make: 0,
                          ),
                        ];
                        int duration = 0;
                        print(historySnapshot.data!.first);
                        historySnapshot.data!
                            .map((WorkoutHistory workoutHistory) {
                          print('map historySnapshot start');
                          duration += workoutHistory.duration;
                          workoutSnapshot.data!.map((workout) {
                            print('map workoutSnapshot start');
                            for (int k = 0; k < workout.drillList.length; k++) {
                              for (int j = 0; j < zoneList.length; j++) {
                                if (workout.drillList[k].zone == j) {
                                  zoneList[j].attempt +=
                                      workout.drillList[k].reps;
                                  if (zoneList[j].attempt > 0) {
                                    zoneList[j].status = ZoneStatus.isCompleted;
                                  }
                                  int drillMake = workoutHistory.drillMakes[k];
                                  zoneList[j].make += drillMake;
                                }
                              }
                            }
                            print('map workoutSnapshot end');
                          });
                          print('map historySnapshot end');
                        });
                        print('Duration: $duration sec');
                        print('zoneList[0] make: ${zoneList[0].make}');
                        print('Carousel logic end');
                        return Carousel(zoneList: zoneList, duration: duration);
                      }
                    });
              },
            ),
          ),
```

Here is FirestoreUtils:

```
import 'package:cloud_firestore/cloud_firestore.dart';
import 'package:firebase_auth/firebase_auth.dart'; 
import 'package:make_it_count/utils/drill.dart';
import 'package:make_it_count/utils/workout.dart';
import 'package:make_it_count/utils/workout_history.dart';


class FirestoreUtils {
  FirestoreUtils(this._firestore);

  final FirebaseFirestore _firestore;
  final User? _user = FirebaseAuth.instance.currentUser;
  static const String DATA_COLLECTION = 'data';
  static const String USERS_DOCUMENT = 'users';
  static const String WORKOUTS_DOCUMENT = 'workouts';
  static const String QUICK_WORKOUTS_COLLECTION = 'quick_workouts';
  static const String NAME_FIELD = 'name';
  static const String EMAIL_FIELD = 'email';
  static const String WORKOUT_FIELD = 'workout';
  static const String WORKOUT_HISTORY_FIELD = 'workout_histories';
  static const String COMPLETED_TIME_FIELD = 'completedTime';


  Stream<List<WorkoutHistory>> getWorkoutHistoryListStreamByTime(
      DateTime startTime, DateTime endTime) {
    return _firestore
        .collection(DATA_COLLECTION)
        .doc(USERS_DOCUMENT)
        .collection(_user!.uid)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) {
      List<WorkoutHistory> workoutHistoryList = [];

      for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.docs[0][WORKOUT_HISTORY_FIELD].length; i++) {
        if (snapshot.docs[0][WORKOUT_HISTORY_FIELD][i][COMPLETED_TIME_FIELD]
                .toDate()
                .isAfter(startTime) &&
            snapshot.docs[0][WORKOUT_HISTORY_FIELD][i][COMPLETED_TIME_FIELD]
                .toDate()
                .isBefore(endTime)) {
          workoutHistoryList.add(WorkoutHistory.fromJson(
              snapshot.docs[0][WORKOUT_HISTORY_FIELD][i]));
        }
      }

      return workoutHistoryList;
    });
  }

  Stream<List<Workout>> getWorkoutListStream() {
    return _firestore
        .collection(DATA_COLLECTION)
        .doc(WORKOUTS_DOCUMENT)
        .collection(QUICK_WORKOUTS_COLLECTION)
        .snapshots()
        .map((snapshot) {
      List<Workout> workoutList = [];

      for (int i = 0; i < snapshot.docs.length; i++) {
        workoutList.add(Workout.fromJson(snapshot.docs[i][WORKOUT_FIELD]));
      }

      return workoutList;
    });
  }
}
```

What is the problem and how to fix it? Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem solved, by converting the two mappings into for loops. But still not sure the reasons behind it.